# Recommended file structure by Google, for the new Android App Architecture

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

On 14 December 2021, Google launched a **[revamped guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide)**, where each Android app shall have at least UI and data layers. Based on the Google documentation regarding this new recommended architecture I can not find any reference to the file structure to adopt.

So I ask if there is any **recommendation by Google** for the file structure to adopt that best fits this architecture.

This question isn`t opinion-based, as I specifically ask for a recommendation from Google.

Answer (score 2):

Very recently, 31 Jan 2022, Manuel Vivo, Android Developer Relations Engineer @ Google, working on App Architecture, respond [here](https://youtu.be/CQzuFZjiUMs?t=2807) to this same question, which I reproduce:

> "That is actually a pretty good question, we do not have one (recommended architecture) at the moment, and that is something we want to work on, which is more about modularization, on how to structure your packages and folders and all that."